# Переворачивается персонаж помогите

Tags: c#, unity3d

Помогите решить данную проблему. После того как начинает персонаж движение он переворачивается на стыке с другой картой почему это происходит и как это исправить кто знает помогите пожалуйста. Смена персонажа на другой не помогла.

[image]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Можно увидеть ваш код?

Comment: По приколу, ради интереса, ознакомтесь с функционалом Rigidbody в испекторе.